# UITextView get selected text point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I was wondering is there any way to get the point of the selected text in UITextView ?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by point ? You mean x & y coordinates ?

Comment: You really cannot do that with the methods defined by apple (unless you work around it, using the point at which cursor is... ) What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I have an UIMenuController and I want to display an UIPopoverController within the selected word after the UIMenuController clicked

Answer (score 2):

For iOS5 and above : Now `UITextField` and `UITextView` conform to `UITextInput` protocol so it is possible :)

Selecting the last 5 characters before the caret would be like this:

```
//Get current selected range , this example assumes is an insertion point or empty selection
UITextRange *selectedRange = [textField selectedTextRange];

NSLog("Start: %d <> End: %d", selectedRange.start, selectedRange.end);

//Calculate the new position, - for left and + for right
UITextPosition *newPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:selectedRange.start offset:-5];

//Construct a new range using the object that adopts the UITextInput, our textfield
UITextRange *newRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:newPosition toPosition:selectedRange.start];
```

Comment: I thought the question meant, CGPointMake(x,y) coordinates of the location in which it is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first get the active selection like this:  `myTextView.selectedRange` and then pass it to this method `[myTextView firstRectForRange:range]`  This will give you the first bounding rectangle (which is the entire selection if it is one line, and the area of the selection on the first line if it is multi-line) as a `CGRect`.