# how to select a word in UITextView?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextview

I'm implementing a Reader App, which allows user tap a word to get the definition, because I need to support iOS 5, I can't use UILabel because it doesn't support attribute string. I want to know how to detect a tap to a word can show background color in uITextView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318283/selecting-a-word-in-a-uitextview and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680432/uitextview-get-selected-text-point